# ReactJS: Page not being re-rendered on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I am learning react through the university of helsinki's full stack open course. The point of the code is there are two buttons and a quote shown on page. One button goes to a random quote and the other lets you put in a vote and shows how many votes that quote has total. The problem is that when I click vote, it adds the vote in the background but doesn't re-render the total amount of votes unless I change the quote.

I've tried different ways to go about conducting state change such as creating a function specifically for the setVote but I can't get it to work.

```
const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  let [vote, setVote] = useState([...copyVote])

  const changeAnecdote = () => {
    setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))
  }

  const addVote = () => {
    copyVote[selected] = copyVote[selected] + 1
    setVote(vote = copyVote)
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={changeAnecdote} text='Next Anecdote'/>
        <Button onClick={addVote} text='Vote'/>
        <div>
          {anecdotes[selected]}
          <DisplayVotes vote={vote} selected={selected}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

copyVote is a copy of a zero-filled array and DisplayVotes simply shows how many votes total for that quote on screen.

When I check for changes in the array of votes after hitting vote through developer tools, the array doesn't change until I go to another quote.
Anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `setVote(vote)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few things that should be updated here.

Firstly, `copyVote` is an array containing the number of votes for each quote. So `...copyVote` will give you each item in that array. You only want the vote for the current quote. Your initial `vote` state should be

```
const [vote, setVote] = useState(copyVote[selected])
```

You also want to update the `addVote` function the way DSCH mentioned.

```
const addVote = () => {
  // copyVote[selected]++ is the same as copyVote[selected] += 1 and copyVote[selected] = copyVote[selected] + 1 
  setVote(copyVote[selected]++)
}
```

Finally, you want to add a way to update the vote each time the anecdote is changed. You could do this in the `changeAnecdote` function, but a better approach would be to use an effect hook that is dependent on the `selected` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Set the value of vote to match the newly selected quote
  setVote(copyVote[selected])
}, [selected])
```

Using this, the `DisplayVotes` `vote` prop is only going to display the vote for the currently selected quote. You may need to updated that component to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In `setVote(vote = copyVote)` the expression within the parentheses is an expression to set the `vote` variable with the value in `copyVote`. I assume that's why you use `let` in `let [vote, setVote] = useState([...copyVote])`, since probably you got an error setting a value to a `const`.
As `setVote` is what return from the `useState` what you probably want to do is:

```
const addVote = () => {
    copyVote[selected] = copyVote[selected] + 1
    setVote(copyVote[selected])
}
```